# Cant call a js function from button

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I make a .hta program that fires other files. If i fire it directly from js, i can open it. The problem is, i cant run js functions from buttons with onclick. Its my code: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=ge80d80b4f0bed7359999532564e023151da1480dd

Answer (score 2):

Create a new blank html file using notepad and move your html content in that file. This will remove the special char which is only showing in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all the *meta*, *link* and *style* infromations to the *head* tag and then remove the *& # 65270 ;* from start of the *body*. That seems to solve the problem for me.